# Powershell - How to display next $line in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, line

I am currently parsing strings from .cpp files and need a way to display string blocks of multiple lines using the _T syntax. To exclude one line _T strings, I included a -notmatch ";" parameter to exclude them. This also excludes the last line of the string block, which I need. So I need to display the next string, so that the last string block with ";" is included.

I tried $foreach.moveNext() | out-file C:/T_Strings.txt -append but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
    foreach ($line in $allLines)

    {

    $lineNumber++

    if ($line -match "^([0-9\s\._\)\(]+$_=<>%#);" -or $line -like "*#*" -or $line -like "*\\*" -or $line -like "*//*" -or $line -like "*.dll* *.exe*")
    {
        continue
    } 

    if ($line -notlike "*;*" -and $line -match "_T\(\""" ) # Multiple line strings
    {
        $line | out-file C:/T_Strings.txt -append
        $foreach.moveNext() | out-file C:/T_Strings.txt -append
    }
```

Comment: Need example input data to see what you're working with. Which lines are getting removed, and which ones aren't (but should be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, `$foreach` isn't a variable, so you can't call a method on it.  If you want an iterator, you'll need to create one:

```
$iter = $allLines.GetEnumerator()

do
{
    $iter.MoveNext()
    $line = $iter.Current
    if( -not $line )
    {
        break
    }
} while( $line )
```

I would recommend you don't use regular expressions, though.  Parse the C++ files instead.  Here's the simplest thing I could think of to parse out *all* _T strings.  It doesn't handle:

- commented out _T strings
- a ") in the _T string
- a _T string at the end of a file.

You'll have to add those checks yourself.  If you only want multi-line _T strings, you'll have to filter out single line strings, too.

```
$inString = $false
$strings = @()
$currentString = $null

$file = $allLines -join "`n"
$chars = $file.ToCharArray()
for( $idx = 0; $idx < $chars.Length; ++$idx )
{
    $currChar = $chars[$idx]
    $nextChar = $chars[$idx + 1]
    $thirdChar = $chars[$idx + 2]
    $fourthChar = $chars[$idx + 3]

    # See if the current character is the start of a new _T token
    if( -not $inString -and $currChar -eq '_' -and $nextChar -eq 'T' -and $thirdChar -eq '(' -and $fourthChar -eq '"' )
    {
        $idx += 3
        $inString = $true
        continue
    }

    if( $inString )
    {
        if( $currChar -eq '"' -and $nextChar -eq ')' )
        {
            $inString = $false
            if( $currentString )
            {
                $strings += $currentString
            }
            $currentString = $null
        }
        else
        {
            $currentString += $currChar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped out tremendously.

Comment: What Powershell version are you using? I have V5 and there's no such thing as ".GetEnumerator()" ...

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the syntax to do this:

```
$foreach.movenext()
$foreach.current | out-file C:/T_Strings.txt -append
```

You need to move to the next, then pipe the current foreach value.